# How to test django non-REST POST endpoint?

Tags: django

I'm having trouble testing one of my endpoints:

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def store(request):
    try:
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = ast.literal_eval(body_unicode)
        new_short_url = body['short_url']
        original_url = body['original_url']
        check_parameters(new_short_url, original_url)
        Url.objects.create(short_url=new_short_url, original_url=original_url)
        return HttpResponse('Created', status=201)
    except KeyError as error:
        return HttpResponse('Missing {}'.format(error.args), status=400)
    except (AttributeError, IntegrityError, ValidationError) as error:
        return HttpResponse(error.args, status=400)
```

As you can see, this endpoint only accepts POST requests and when trying to pass data from my tests, it arrives in the request.body, so I implemented my logic to get the data from there:

```
  def test_create_url_ok(self):
        creation_data = {
            "short_url": "ab",
            "original_url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        }

        response = self.client.post(reverse('store'), data=creation_data, content_type="application/json")

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

This works, but the problem is that when sending requests from my templates, data is not in the request.body, but in the request.POST. How to send data in the request.POST from my tests?

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing is that vanilla django accepts data from request.POST when the content_type='multipart/form-data'. Since I was using 'json' it wasn't working (though it works when using DjangoRestFramework views):

[image: example]

When using default django tests, this content_type is the default, so you don't need to specify any:

[image: test]